# connection property not initialized. i am trying to insert data in two table

Tags: c#

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["abc"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd;


    cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into student (name,email,mobile,userid,pass) values('"+textBox1.Text+"','"+textBox2.Text+"','"+textBox3.Text+"','"+textBox4.Text+"','"+textBox5.Text+"')", con);

    cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into course (stid) select top (1) stid from student order by stid desc", con);

    cmd = new SqlCommand("update course set coursename ='"+comboBox1.Text+"'where stid =  top (1) stid from course order by stid desc",con); 
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

i am trying to insert data in two table using a single form with primary and foreign key relation stid is primary key in table student and foreign key in course

Comment: Hope you are aware of SQL Injection.

Comment: You understand that the first two SqlCommands you're creating aren't being used, right?

Comment: Your first two commands wont execute.Only the third command executes since you are replacing the command  cmd two times.

Comment: thanks  jon skeet its my mistake to make this silly mistake ....now my issue is solve.

Answer (score 0):

Your queries should be like this

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["abc"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd;

con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into student (name,email,mobile,userid,pass) values('"+textBox1.Text+"','"+textBox2.Text+"','"+textBox3.Text+"','"+textBox4.Text+"','"+textBox5.Text+"')", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();//Foreach query you need to execute this line

cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into course (stid) select top (1) stid from student order by stid desc", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();//Foreach query you need to execute this line

cmd = new SqlCommand("update course set coursename ='"+comboBox1.Text+"'where stid =  top (1) stid from course order by stid desc",con); 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();//Foreach query you need to execute this line


con.Close();
```

Comment: cmd = new SqlCommand("update course set coursename =@coursename where course.stid = (select  top (1) stid from course order by stid desc)",con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@coursename", comboBox1.Text.ToString());

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues in your code:

**Issue 1:** The first two commands

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into student (name,email,mobile,userid,pass) values('"+textBox1.Text+"','"+textBox2.Text+"','"+textBox3.Text+"','"+textBox4.Text+"','"+textBox5.Text+"')", con);

cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into course (stid) select top (1) stid from student order by stid desc", con);
```

are not being used. You need to use the ExecuteNonQuery to get them executed. At present only the third command will be executed.

The error which you are getting

> connection property not initialized

is because you need to assign the connection to the SqlCommand.

**Issue 2:** Your code is open to SQL Injection. You need to use parameterized query to get rid of that.(*It is highly recommended.*)

**Issue 3:** Try to use `using` statement to deal with `SqlConnection` as that would automatically close your connection once you are done with your execution.